# Wordpress custom post types for different styled paragraphs

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

My homepage has content that look's something like:

```
<section id="about">
    <p class="quote">
    </p>
    <div class="text">
        <h2></h2>
        <p></p>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="about-photo">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
</section>

<section id="mission">
    <div class="text">
        <h2></h2>
        <p></p>
    </div>
</section>
```

I was wondering whether the way to reproduce this structure in a CMS would be to create custom post types. My reasoning is that I have different types of p tags (".quote", and a non-classified "p"). From all the examples that I've seen, however, it does not seem like custom post types get used this way. That is, using two separate fields for "paragraph-like" information.

Comment: It's very hard to answer what would be best, but it seems a little **to much** to add a new content type just to add a class. You should be able to achive this by adding a new kind of template or some conditional code in a existing one. Another way would be to just write css for the different `p` elements in regards to their parent element ie: `p { ... } #about p { ... }` and so on.

Comment: I thought about writing different CSS in regards to the parent element. The issue here is that I believe this solution only works if you identify what text belongs to the ".quote" class by adding html tags (<p style="class"), in the text editor portion of Wordpress. People who will use my CMS will likely only know how to operate the visual editor. If I were to try to achieve this through a new template, how would I differentiate which content goes in which "p" tag. Doesn't "the_content( )", retrieve all the text in one swoop?

Comment: Like I said it's very hard to give any answer without knowing more about your theme and so on. You could have a look at the "Advanced Custom Fields" plugin. Using that you could for instance add a custom field to your ordinary post content-type. This field could be a checkbox stating if the post should have a `p.quote` class, you would then read the value of the checkbox in your template before rendering the post ie `$value = get_field('my_field'); $cssClass = ($value == 1 ? "quote" : "");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did exactly this a while ago. If you do not mind paying a little bit for a great plugin.

Step 1: Get the advanced Custom Fields Plugin - Awesome for Custom fields and really simple to add to you template.

Step 2: Buy the repeater field plugin for Advanced Custom Fields

Step 3: Install plugins.

Step 4: Create the custom fields by creating a repeater field with two sub fields. The two sub fields should be paragraph and class. Be sure check the strip html setting for the class field.

Step 5: Add to template.

You can even make the class field a select list if you have predefined values.

Comment: Why would he need a repeater field to do this? He just needs to add a new field group and connect to new text fields to it, then attach this field group to the 'post' type content type.

Comment: A repeater fields gives him the opportunity to the different classes freely without a being confined to a strict temple, he can now add variations of his different class and repeat them where required.

Comment: Took me a couple days to realize that this is the right response. While what I wanted to do seemed so simple, it appears it can only be achieved through a plug-in (granted it is achieved by one of the most downloaded plug-ins available).

Comment: Yeah, I basically use the ACF plugin on every Wordpress site. Look, you can do all of this manually but I have found that this really adds tons of time to your project... I used it for the section here: http://howlmedia.co.za/portfolio/redespresso/

Answer (score 0):

you can do like below:

- Create the custom post type with tag.
- Add the number of post in this post type with unique tag name.
- create the loop with all thie post type and in this loop set the condition like,

  `if(post tag name == "about")
  {
      // you "about" style selection div
  }else if(post tag name == "about-photo"){
      // you "about-photo" style selection div
  }else if(post tag name == "mission"){
     // you "mission" style selection div
  }`